# How to save webpages's url via uiwebview to a table with Swift ios8

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, ios8, uiwebview

**Technologies Used: Swift, ios8, xCode 6**

I'm using the uiwebview to load a website into my app. The user can click around to different pages of the website.

I want the user to have the option to save the url of the page they happen to be on.

And if they go to another page within the website, to be able to save that page's url and so on and so forth.

What is the best way to accomplish this in swift?

Answer (score 1):

I've used something like this before:

```
let webView = UIWebView()
if let urlString = webView.stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString( "window.location.href" ),
    let pageURL = NSURL(string: urlString) {
    // Save the URL
}
```

Comment: thanks for your help. looks like I can grab the url, now I just need to figure out how to save it to a table so users can access whenever they want